# Random.randint not generating a random number in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, random, while-loop

This function (`playCraps()`) is supposed to choose two random integers between 1 and 6, sum them up, and return a `True` or `False` value held in `x`.
For some reason, each time I run the program, it always returns `True` with either 7 or 11.

```
import random

wins = [7, 11]
losses = [2, 3, 12]

def playCraps():
    x = 0 
    while x == 0:
       sumDice = random.randint(1,6) + random.randrange(1,6) 
       if sumDice in wins:
           x = True 
       elif sumDice in losses:
           x = False 
       else:
           sumDice = 0 
print("The sum of the dice was " + str(sumDice)) 
print("So the boolean value is " + str(x))
```

Why does this happen? And how can this be fixed?

Comment: This is not valid python code. Could you please fix the indentation, such that we can track down the error?

Comment: Is the indentation correct?

Answer (score 2):

You always get `True` because your `while` loop will execute even if `x` is `False`. 0 is a *falsy* value in Python. Example:

```
>>> x = False
>>> if x == 0:
        print 'x == 0 is falsy'
x == 0 is falsy
```

So your loop will eventually give `True` no matter what. A possible solution will be to define:

```
x = False 
while not x:
    ...
```

Comment: should be `while not x`

Comment: This was my issue, and I can see what I was doing wrong now. Thank you!

Comment: @rlfrick Glad it worked, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You won't exit the `while x == 0:` loop until `x` is equal to `True`.
Because `0 == x`